# Range not found in Google Apps Script. How make a loop?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to execute the following code and it does not work for me

I have recorded a macro for Google Sheets and it has the following code

```
    /** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function ValidacionDatos() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D3').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
  .requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('Main!$F$3:$H$3'), true)
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getRange('D3').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
  .requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('Main!$F$3:$H$3'), true)
  .build());
spreadsheet.getRange('D4').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
.requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('Main!$F$4:$H$4'), true)
  .build());
spreadsheet.getRange('D5').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
.requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('Main!$F$5:$H$5'), true)
  .build());
};
```

... etc. So until 77

I would like to know how to loop until row 77, instead of having to write so much code.

I had written this:

```
function ValidacionDatosBucle() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D5').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Desarrollo'), true);
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D5').activate();
  var numfila = 3;
while (numfila < 10){
  spreadsheet.getRange('D5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D5').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
  .requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange('Main!$F$'&numfila&':$H$'&numfila), true)
  .build());
  numfila = numfila++
  }
```

And I get this error: Range not found in line 10, file macros

Comment: What is the location of the validation fields? I it is the same for the entire column or does it change as you go down?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply.

I was trying to do is complete the cells of a certain column by applying data validation - List from interval. This interval must be given to each cell of the corresponding column, for example, column D. This is to create a conditioned drop-down list.

In the end I did the following:

```
function Validacion2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var fila = 3
  var col = 'D'
  var hoja = 'Main'
  spreadsheet.getRange('C8:C10').activate();
  while (fila < 14){
     spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(hoja), true);
     spreadsheet.getRange('F'+fila+':H'+fila).activate();
     spreadsheet.getRange('D'+fila).setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
     .setAllowInvalid(true)
     .requireValueInRange(spreadsheet.getRange(hoja+'!$F$'+fila+':$H$'+fila), true)
     .build());
     fila = fila+=1 
     }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want here is for column D to be restricted to the values in F through H of the equivalent row on Main.

If so this is what you do:

```
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ss = sh.getActiveSheet(); // THIS SHEET
var os = sh.getSheetByName("Main"); // THE MAIN SHEET WITH VALIDATION VALUES
var data = os.getRange("F:H").getValues();//VALIDATION VALUES

for (var i=2; i<ss.getLastRow;i++) //lets go through your entire current sheet, starts in row 2)
    {
    var options = data[i-1];//get validatoins for just this row, offset because array
    var dv = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation();
    dv.setAllowInvalid(false);
    dv.requireValueInList(options, true);
    ss.getRange(i,4).setDataValidation(dv);

    }//for loop
```

This won't be blazingly fast but should be able to get through all 77 rows before time out.